# How to fix press button problem on chrome?

Tags: javascript, android, button

I have a game. When I click the right button then the element moves. When I press tge button then show downloading menu and element does not move. The problem is in Chrome on Android.

```
$('#right').on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
  timeOut2 = setInterval(function() {
    delta = 5;
  }, 25);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave touchend', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  clearInterval(timeOut2);
});
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to handle both mouse and touch events for a button in your game using jQuery. The issue you're facing might be related to the touch events on Chrome for Android. To address this, you can modify your code to use the touchstart, touchmove, and touchend events specifically for touch devices. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
 $('#right').on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default action for touchstart on mobile devices
  timeOut2 = setInterval(function() {
    delta = 5;
  }, 25);
}).on('mouseup mouseleave touchend touchcancel', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  clearInterval(timeOut2);
});
```